# Ubuntu 16.04 + Bitnami WP AWS+ Webmin Installation Fails + E: Package [] has no installation candidate

Tags: apt, server, package-management, webmin

I also have an open thread on [Bitnami's support forum](https://community.bitnami.com/t/webmin-installation-fails-e-package-has-no-installation-candidate/55802). I've installed [WordPress Multisite Certified by Bitnami](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00NN8XE6S) via the AWS marketplace.

I'm trying to install webmin (or any package, really) and can't

Via SSH, I run:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install perl libnet-ssleay-perl openssl libauthen-pam-perl libpam-runtime libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python
```

Which outputs:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libnet-ssleay-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libauthen-pam-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package libio-pty-perl is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package apt-show-versions is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package python is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libnet-ssleay-perl' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libauthen-pam-perl' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libio-pty-perl' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'apt-show-versions' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'python' has no installation candidate
```

I've tried a bunch of fixes and it seems there's something that needs to be tweaked in /etc/apt/sources.list ...the weird thing is that this file is empty.

I've also tried

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
```

...then..

```
sudo apt-get -f install webmin
```

...which outputs

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 webmin : Depends: libnet-ssleay-perl but it is not installable
          Depends: libauthen-pam-perl but it is not installable
          Depends: libio-pty-perl but it is not installable
          Depends: apt-show-versions but it is not installable
          Depends: python but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to populate /etc/apt/sources.list ?
This is my fie for 16.04 in aws:

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v '#'
```

> deb http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main
>   restricted deb-src http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   xenial main restricted
>
> deb http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates
>   main restricted deb-src
>   http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main
>   restricted
>
> deb http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
>   deb-src http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial
>   universe deb http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   xenial-updates universe deb-src
>   http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates
>   universe
>
> deb http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
>   deb-src http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial
>   multiverse deb http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
>   xenial-updates multiverse deb-src
>   http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates
>   multiverse
>
> deb http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports
>   main restricted universe multiverse deb-src
>   http://eu-west-2.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main
>   restricted universe multiverse
>
> deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
>   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main
>   restricted deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security
>   universe deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security
>   universe deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security
>   multiverse deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security
>   multiverse

running

> ```
> apt-cache madison  libnet-ssleay-perl libauthen-pam-perl libio-pty-perl apt-show-versions python
> ```

shows packages availble from selected repos

> ```
> libnet-ssleay-perl | 1.72-1build1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
>
> libauthen-pam-perl | 0.16-3build2 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
>
> libio-pty-perl | 1:1.08-1.1build1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
>
> apt-show-versions |     0.22.7 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages 
>
> apt-show-versions |     0.22.7 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe i386 Packages
>
> python | 2.7.12-1~16.04 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
>
> python |   2.7.11-1 | http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
> ```

Hope this will help.
Thanks